# How to get a random song to play using an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, audio, random

The page loads and the rand variable randomizes the song. I want the playagain button to pause the song and call the rand varibale again so it randomises the song again. so when i press the playbutton it will then play a different song. the playagain button is  pausing the song however the rand variable is not randomizing again. is there a way to fix that?

HTML:

```
<audio id="mytrack" controls>
    <source src="Song1.wav" type = "audio/wav"/>
</audio>

<audio id="gd" controls>
    <source src="Song2.mp3" type = "audio/mp3"/>
</audio>

<button type="button" id="playButton"></button>
<button type="button" id="playagain"></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mytrackJS = document.getElementById('mytrack');
var playButtonJS = document.getElementById('playButton');
var playagainJS = document.getElementById('playagain');
var gdJS = document.getElementById('gd');

var audioPlaying = [mytrackJS, gdJS];
var rand = audioPlaying[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length)];

playButtonJS.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
playagainJS.addEventListener('click', random, false);

function random() {

     var rand = [Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length)];
    playOrPause();
}

function playOrPause() {
    if (!rand.paused && !rand.ended){
        rand.pause();
        playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(playbutton.svg)';
    }
    else{
        rand.play();
        playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(pausebutton.png)';
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, there is a typo in `playagainJS.addEventListener('clcik', random, false);`, which should probably be `click` instead of `clcik`. Also, why are you selecting a random element from a list of HTML elements?

Comment: thanks i fixed the typo. im trying to get it to randomly pick a song then play it. then when the playagain button is clicked it will pause the song and randomly select another song

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're declaring the variable audioPlaying correctly.  You also don't need audioPlaying[] surrounding your statement for rand.  Try this instead:

```
var audioPlaying = [mytrackJS, gdJS];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length);
```

Comment: Oh just saw that thanks. ive changed it but its still not working

Comment: Just added a quick update.  regarding the 'rand' variable.  Let me know how that works now

Comment: ok thanks. its now randomizing the songs. theres some issues with the play and pause not working but i think i should be able to fix that. thanks

Comment: If `rand` is just a number, how will `rand.pause()` and `rand.play()` succeed?

Comment: @user7834246 how is that working now? As per your code, **rand** variable seems to be an instance of song on which you could execute play/pause whereas this answer suggests it to be a random number.

Comment: it is playing and pausing. however ive put my rand variable inside the function and that means that this line:  if (!rand.paused && !rand.ended){... is not going to work when i click the button again. as if the rand variable chooses the other song then it starts plaything the song with the old song still in the background

Comment: ive changed the question ive asked. could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Since you initialized **rand** variable once, its value is going to remain the same throughout.

To see expected results move it to **playOrPause** function.

```
function playOrPause() {
  var rand = audioPlaying[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length)];
  if (!rand.paused && !rand.ended){
    rand.pause();
    playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(playbutton.svg)';
  } else{
    rand.play();
    playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(pausebutton.png)';
  }
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is a pretty useless statement. You need to be very explicit and define exactly what is failing and how.

Comment: I'm trying to press the play button and get a random song to play from an array list. I also have anothe button which when pressed calls up a function which randomises the song again. However the random function isn't being called. I've added alert messages into it and the messages aren't popping up. Is there something missing which would explain why the random function is not being called

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but instead of selecting between two different `audio` elements, I would just change the `src` attribute of a single one. This way you could have an array of file names and randomly select from those using `array[Math.random()*array.length]`

Comment: an you explain how i would change the `src` attribute

Comment: `document.getElementById('mytrack').src = array[Math.random()*array.length]`